# Why doesn't this ruby code compare regex?

Tags: ruby

```
if string == /\s{1,}/ or string == /\n{1,}/
  puts "emptiness..."
end
```

Answer (score 27):

To test a `String` against a `Regex`, you can do any of five things:

1: Use `String#match`:

```
' '.match /\s{1,}/    # => #<MatchData:0x118ca58>
'f'.match /\s{1,}/    # => nil
```

2: Use `Regex#match`:

```
/\s{1,}/.match ' '    # => <MatchData:0x11857e4>
/\s{1,}/.match 'f'    # => nil
```

3: Use `String#=~`:

```
' ' =~ /\s{1,}/       # => 0
'f' =~ /\s{1,}/       # => nil
```

4: Use `Regex#=~`:

```
/\s{1,}/ =~ ' '       # => 0
/\s{1,}/ =~ 'f'       # => nil
```

5: Use `Regex#===` (this is what is used in `case` statements):

```
/\s{1,}/ === ' '      # => true
/\s{1,}/ === 'f'      # => false
```

Note: `String#===` **doesn't** do what you want:

```
' ' === /\s{1,}/      # => false
'f' === /\s{1,}/      # => false
```

Answer (score 7):

When comparing with regexes in Ruby, you should use the '=~' comparison instead of '=='.

Try that and see if it gives you what you expect.